# .NET - MySQL query parameter from non user input

Tags: c#, mysql, prepared-statement

I understand that using parameters with your queries prevents SQL injection (when obtaining values from user input). But if I wanted to construct a query that uses predefined values e.g.

```
MySqlCommand Command = Connection.CreateCommand();
Command.CommandText = "SELECT employee_address FROM employees WHERE employee_name = @employee_name";
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("employee_name", "John");
```

Can I not use this instead?

```
MySqlCommand Command = Connection.CreateCommand();
Command.CommandText = "SELECT employee_address FROM employees WHERE employee_name = 'John'";
```

Is it necessary to use parameters in this scenario?

Can I also do it this way?

```
string employee_name = "John"; //value depends on some sort of selection (not user input)

MySqlCommand Command = Connection.CreateCommand();
Command.CommandText = "SELECT employee_address FROM employees WHERE employee_name = '" + employee_name + "'";
```

Comment: If you don't take this `'John'` as an input, no, not necessary.

Comment: Then your code is fine

Comment: @Joachim - See the UPDATE - the value 'John' may be something else say e.g. 'Jack' depending on some sort of selection, would that make any difference?

Comment: @langjacques Actually, reading up on the subject, it seems MySQL still only has a query cache, not a query _plan_ cache. The query cache will not have any impact on your parameterization, while a query plan cache would have had. In other words, the statements should behave the same cache wise, parameterized or not.

Comment: @Joachim - OK, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend always using parameters. With a string it is simple, but guess you have a boolean, decimal or date. It helps not to think about the formatting.

With parameters your sql-statement can be shorter if you use @0, @1, @2. You could even write a function with a param-array which replaces according to the order of @0, @1, @2. This saves a lot of code. (e.g. ExecuteSql(sql as string, paramarray myParameters as object)